# Get store configuration variable for addLink in local.xml

Tags: helper, local.xml, toplinks

I'm am using the addLink method of Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links in my local.xml, which uses links.phtml as a template.

Is there some way of passing links.phtml the store email/phone addresses which I would normally get from from Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone')?

I.e. something like:

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink">
                <url>tel:<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone') ?></url>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you could use a helper...
<url helper="name/of/helper" />

Comment: ya I guess I'm wondering which one :-)

Comment: I thinke there is no predefined you should write a module

Comment: that's what I was afraid of...new to Magento and while there are a bunch of tutorials out there for making modules I'm overwhelmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your local.xml or your module's layout xml file.

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="your_module"><label>Phone</label><url helper="your_module/getSiteTelephone"/><title>Phone</title></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This will in the end call your helper `Your_Module_Helper_Data->getSiteTelephone`. In your helper you can then use the following code.

```
public function getSiteTelephone() {
    return 'tel:' . Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
}
```

Sadly there is no helper that already does what you need but if you have a module already then it is very simply to add a function into your helper.